# Finding the origin environment of the ... (dots) arguments of a call

Tags: r, rlang

I want to be able to find the environment from which the `...` (dots) arguments of a call originate.

### Scenario

For example, consider a function

```
foo <- function(x, ...) {
  # do something
}
```

We want a function `env_dots()`, which we invoke from within `foo()`, that finds the originating environment of the `...` in a call to `foo()`, even when the call to `foo()` is deeply nested. That is, if we define

```
foo <- function(x, ...) {
  # find the originating environment of '...'
  env <- env_dots()

  # do something
}
```

and nest a call to `foo`, like so,

```
baz <- function(...) {
  a <- "You found the dots"
  bar(1, 2)
}
bar <- function(...)
  foo(...)
```

then calling `baz()` should return the environment in which the `...` in the (nested) call to `foo(...)` originates: this is the environment where the call `bar(1, 2)` is made, since the `2` (but not the `1`) gets passed to the dots of `foo`. In particular, we should get

```
baz()$a
#> [1] "You found the dots"
```

### Naive implementation of `env_dots()`

**Update** — `env_dots()`, as defined here, will *not* work in general, because the final `...` may be populated by arguments that are called at multiple levels of the call stack.

Here's one possibility for `env_dots()`:

```
# mc: match.call() of function from which env_dots() is called
env_dots <- function(mc) {
  # Return NULL if initial call invokes no dots
  if (!rlang::has_name(mc, "...")) return(NULL)

  # Otherwise, climb the call stack until the dots origin is found
  stack <- rlang::call_stack()[-1]
  l <- length(stack)
  i <- 1
  while (i <= l && has_dots(stack[[i]]$expr)) i <- i + 1
  # return NULL if no dots invoked
  if (i <= l) stack[[i + 1]]$env else NULL
}

# Does a call have dots?
has_dots <- function(x) {
  if (is.null(x))
    return(FALSE)
  args <- rlang::lang_tail(x)
  any(vapply(args, identical, logical(1), y = quote(...)))
}
```

This seems to work: with

```
foo <- function(x, ...)
  env_dots(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE))
```

we get

```
baz()$a
#> [1] "You found the dots"

bar(1, 2)  # 2 gets passed down to the dots of foo()
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

bar(1)     # foo() captures no dots
#> NULL
```

### Questions

The above implementation of `env_dots()` is not very efficient.

1. Is there are more skillful way to implement `env_dots()` in **rlang** and/or **base R**?
2. <s>How can I move the `match.call()` invocation to within `env_dots()`?</s>
   `match.call(sys.function(-1), call = sys.call(-1), expand.dots = FALSE)` will indeed work.

*Remark* — One can't infer the origin environment of the dots from `rlang::quos(...)`, because some quosures won't be endowed with the calling environment (e.g., when an expression is a literal object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to dig up an old question, but I'm not sure the desired behavior is well-defined. `...` is not a single expression; it's a list of expressions. In case of `rlang` quosures, each of those expressions has their own environment. So what should the environment of the list be?

Furthermore, the `...` list itself can be modified. Consider the following example, where `g` takes its `...`, prepends it with an (unevaluated) expression `x+3` and passes it onto `f`.

```
f <- function(...) {rlang::enquos( ... )}

g <- function(...) {
  a <- rlang::quo( x + 3 )
  l <- rlang::list2( a, ... )
  f(!!!l)
}

b <- rlang::quo( 5 * y )

g( b, 10 )
# [[1]]
# <quosure>
#   expr: ^x + 3
#   env:  0x7ffd1eca16f0

# [[2]]
# <quosure>
#   expr: ^5 * y
#   env:  global

# [[3]]
# <quosure>
#   expr: ^10
#   env:  empty
```

Notice that each of the three quosures that make it over to `f` has their own environment. (As you noted in your question, literals like `10` have an empty environment. This is because the value is the same independent of which environment it's evaluated in.)

Given this scenario, what should the hypothetical `env_dots()` return when called inside `f()`?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct. The problem is ill-posed. Thanks.